# Serious generics issue: int vs. Integer java

Tags: java, generics, types, int

for a long while, i have been trying to get a piece of code to work, and it just is not possible. the class i have requires a generic   which i have set to Integer. so i tried the follwoing:

```
public class a<T> //set generics for this function
{
    private T A;
    protected boolean d;

    public a(final T A)
    {
        this.A = A;

        //do calculations
        //since constructor cannot return a value, pass to another function.
        this.d = retnData(Integer.parseInt(A.toString()) != 100); //convert to an integer, the backwards way.
    }
    private boolean retnData(boolean test)
    {
        return test;
    }
}
// IN ANOTHER CLASS
transient a<Integer> b;
boolean c = b.d = b.a(25); // throws an erorr: (Int) is not apporpriate for a<Integer>.a
```

Java will not allow this since java sees that int != Integer, even though both accept the same data. and because of the way generics works i cannot set a b; because of the primitiveness of the type int. Even casting to an Integer does not work, as it still throws the "type error"

finnaly, i have to ask if there is some sort of work around for this, or is it futile to try and get this to work?

Comment: It would help a lot if you didn't go out of your way to obfuscate the code each and every person that wants to help you now needs to deobfuscate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to explicitly call a constructor as an instance method. This cannot be done in Java.

Perhaps you want:

```
transient a<Integer> b = new a<Integer>(25);
boolean c = b.d;
```

However, since `d` is declared to be `protected`, that will only work if this code is in another class derived from `a` or in the same package.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
final a<Integer> b = new a<Integer>(10); 
boolean c = b.d;
```

int can be explicitly converted  to Integer with `new Integer(10`) or `Integer.valueOf(10)`

Comment: Prefer `Integer.valueOf(x)` to the `Integer` constructor.  (In particular, it's guaranteed to cache the `Integer` object for 25.)

Comment: You can always pass an `int` to a method that expects an `Integer`.

Comment: `a(Integer)` is a constructor. You can't call `b.a`, regardless of whether you pass an `int` or an `Integer`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman actually in simple use cases `new Integer()` is much faster due to inlining.

Comment: @Ted Hopp Yup, you are absolutely right, I didnt look at code. He called constructor directly instead of something like
final a<Integer> b = new a<Integer>(10);

Answer (score 1):

The code does not make much sense: `b` is an object of type `a`, which does not have an `a` method - so not sure what you expect from `b.a(25)`;... This has nothing to do with `int` vs `Integer`...