# Double vs double in java

Tags: java, methods, double, parameter-passing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java : different double and Double in comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226757/java-different-double-and-double-in-comparison)

In a sample java program for one of my labs, I have two different methods taking Double and double parameters respectively.
How do I differentiate between them when passing arguments to them?

Comment: BTW, the methods have the same signature except for their parameters.

Comment: relevant: [different double and Double in comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12226757/java-different-double-and-double-in-comparison)

Comment: why dont you show your code?

Comment: It's a stub class they have given us. So, it's nothing really but here it is:

Comment: Sorry, I am a newbie. How do I paste my code here?

Comment: @Mahmoud Edit your question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

First off you need to understand the difference between the two types.
`double` is a primitive type whereas `Double` is an Object.

The code below shows an overloaded method, which I assume is similar to your lab code.

```
void doStuff(Double d){ System.out.println("Object call"); }
void doStuff(double d){ System.out.println("Primitive call"); }
```

There are several ways you can call these methods:

```
doStuff(100);
doStuff(200d);
doStuff(new Double(100));
```

These calls will result in:

```
"Primitive call"
"Primitive call"
"Object call"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was so helpful. Didn't know about 200d at all.

Comment: I found the following info more useful when understanding the difference: double is a simple number of type double. Double is a class. It holds a single field of type double, but has built-in functions like .toString() and floatValue(), and can be extended. With a 'double' you'd need to do String.valueOf() to get its string, but with Double you can just to .toString().

Comment: When to use the first and when to use the latter?

Answer (score 36):

`Double` parameter can be `null` when `double` can't.

Comment: Nah, My problems is that I want to call the methods. So, when I am passing arguments to them, I don't know which one it goes to. The one accepting double or the one accepting Double?

Comment: @Mahmoud Always force it to use the primitive `double` version by forcing the Double to unbox into a `double` before passing the parameter.

Comment: @Mahmoud true, primitive doubles are generally best.

Comment: @Andrew I cannot in this case. It's part of the lab instructions.

Comment: @Mahmoud It depends on the static type of the parameter. If it's a primitive type, it will convert to a `double` and call the overload with the primitive. If the static type of the parameter is the class `Double`, then it will call the overload with the boxed type.

Comment: @Mahmoud well, if you have method (interface) that allowed to you set `Double`, it's means that you can provide `null` instead and no crash will happen.

Comment: @Mahmoud (For what it's worth, I find this type of thing in school assignments irritating. It'd be more responsible to first teach good practice, and only then make you drill minutiae and edge cases.)

Answer (score 4):

**-** `double` is a primitive type, where as `Double` is a *wrapper object*.

**-** One of the most common use of Wrapper objects is with `Collection` .

**Eg:**

```
List<Double> d = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

**-** In **Java 5** a mechanism called `Autoboxing` has been introduced to **convert between the two directly.**

**Eg:**

```
double d = 10.41;
Double wrapper = d;
```

Comment: Wrapper objects aren't used with generics, they were used before generics to store primitive types in collections. They're also used in other contexts that call for nullable types. (Notably entity IDs when doing ORM.)

Answer (score 2):

Double is a wrapper class while double is a primitive type like c/c++. As pointed out above, Double is mostly used in generics but also is useful anywhere there is a need for both numerical value and proper object encapsulation. In most cases the Double and double can be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 1):

`Double` is reference type and `double` is value type.

> The `Double` class wraps a value of the primitive type double in an object. An object of type Double contains a single field whose type is double." [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html)

As @Fess mentioned and because `Double` is reference type it can be `null`.

If you want you can explictly convert from `Double` to `double` with `.doubleValue()` method and viceverrsa with `new Double(1.0)`.

Also as @millimoose said:

> You should use `X.valueOf()` instead of `new X()`. The `valueOf` methods are allowed to cache the boxing types to reduce memory use. (Not sure this is done for `Double`s but it's a good habit to get into.)"

Comment: You should almost never need to do this explicit conversion anymore. Autoboxing will insert calls to `doubleValue` and `valueOf` for you based on the context.

Comment: Yes, I know. I changed my answer to "If you want you...". This is almost the same problem as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12846624/serious-generics-issue-int-vs-integer-java/12846665#12846665

Comment: Also I think you should use `X.valueOf()` instead of `new X()`. The `valueOf` methods are allowed to cache the boxing types to reduce memory use. (Not sure this is done for `Double`s but it's a good habit to get into.)

Comment: Yup, i wrote my answer really quickly and I didnt put that. I will edit my answer and put your previous comment quoted on the end

Answer (score 1):

```
// Method A
public static void foo(Double d) {...}

// Method B 
public static void foo(double d) {...}
```

---

Evidently, if you pass a `Double` object then *Method A* will be called; i.e. if you had something like:

```
Double d = new Double(1.0);
```

Further, if you pass a double literal you will call *Method B*. What's interesting is if you have something like

```
double d = new Double(1.0);
```

In this case *Method B* will also be called, because the **type** of `d` is `double`; the `Double` object gets unboxed to a `double`. On the same note, if you had:

```
Double d = 1.0;
```

then *Method A* would be called, because the type of `d` would be `Double` (the `double`-literal gets autoboxed to a `Double`).

Comment: An important aside is that if you *need* to do this sort of differentiation, it's probably a code smell. Ideally one of those overloads should wrap around the other. (In fact, in any set of overloads most should probably ultimately delegate to one of them or a single private implementation method.)

Comment: "double d= new Double(1.0)" is not a subclass/superclass issue. "d is an instantiation of Double" is not true. It's not an instantiation of Double. You are creating an Object Double, then unboxing it into a double. Essentially it's a useless statement.

Comment: "then Method A would be called, because the type of d would be double (and not Double)" - still wrong. `d` would be a `Double`, seeing as *that's how you declared it*.

Comment: Autoboxing doesn't let a variable be of two types at once, or be of a different type than is declared. All the compiler does is automatically insert boxing and unboxing code. This means that `double d1 = new Double(1.0);` gets compiled as `double d1 = new Double(1.0).doubleValue();`. Conversely, `Double d2 = 1.0;` gets compiled to `Double d2 = Double.valueOf(1.0);`. *At no point* is `d1` of type `Double`, or `d2` of type `double`.

Comment: @millimoose Thanks - that was a typo.

Comment: @AndrewFinnell Thanks as well - I edited to reflect your comment.

Comment: @millimoose & AndrewFinnell Thanx guys. Although it got a bit too complicated for me (I am a first year student of Software), still, I could manage to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is an example of [method overloading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html). The good part is that the compiler and the JVM will select the correct method automatically based on the type of the arguments that is used when you call the method.